# Why is my linked list only printing last entry?

Tags: c, file, linked-list

I'm trying to read specific lines from a file and add it to a linked list and then print it out.
Code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

 typedef struct list {
    int uid;
   char* uname;
   struct list* next;
}node;



void push(node ** head, int uid ,char* uname) {
    node * new_node;
    new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));
    new_node->uid = uid ;
    new_node->uname=uname;;
    new_node->next = *head;
    *head = new_node;
}


void print_list(node *head) {
    node * current = head;
    while (current != NULL) {
        printf("%u:%s\n", current->uid,current->uname);
        current = current->next;
    }
}


int main(int argc, char **argv){

    node *current=NULL;
    FILE *fp=fopen(argv[1],"r" );
    if (fp==NULL){
        perror("Failed to open file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    char s[1024];
    const char token[2]=":";
    char *stoken;
    while(!feof(fp)){
        int count=0;
        int tempint;
        char* tempchar=malloc(sizeof(char));
        fgets(s, 1024, fp);
        stoken = strtok(s,token);
        current=malloc(sizeof(node));
        while(stoken != NULL){
            if (count==0){
                tempchar=stoken;
            }
            if (count==2){
                sscanf(stoken,"%d",&tempint);
            }
            count++;
        stoken=strtok(NULL,token);
        }
        push(&current,tempint,tempchar);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    print_list(current);
}
```

My problem is when `print_list` is ran the only thing who gets printed is the last entry.

For this input :

```
hello:asd:123:foo:ar

hi:proto:124:oo:br

hey:qwe:321:fo:bar
```

the only thing which gets printed is

```
321:hey
```

is it my push which is wrong or my print_list?

Comment: I think that there is a need to skip if blank line exists. and `while(!feof(fp)){` --> `while(fgets(s, 1024, fp)){`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the way you are treating the result of `strtok`: you are setting its value right into the node, instead of copying it.

Make a copy of `name` when adding a node:

```
void push(node ** head, int uid ,char* uname) {
    node * new_node;
    new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));
    new_node->uid = uid;
    new_node->uname=malloc(strlen(uname)+1);
    strcpy(new_node->uname, uname);
    new_node->next = *head;
    *head = new_node;
}
```

You should also look at the way that you are using `tempchar` in the `main` function. You allocate a space for a single character to it, which gets written over with the result of `strtok`, leaking the `malloc`-ed memory.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you always overwrite `head` in the `push()` function, you should make it `NULL` initially and then check if it's `NULL` the first time and assign to it the first node, and then don't reassing anything to it, your program has a memory leak because of this too.

Also you are `malloc()`ing the node outside the function and then inside the function again,which causes another memory leak.

You should also check if `malloc()` returns  `NULL` which indicates an error like when the system runs out of memory, dereferencing a `NULL` pointer is undefined behavior.

And a final note, you **must** check the return value of `scanf()` before accessing the target variables, or that would again cause undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

change like as follows

```
char* tempchar;//=malloc(sizeof(char));
fgets(s, 1024, fp);
stoken = strtok(s,token);
//current=malloc(sizeof(node));//don't update like this
while(stoken != NULL){
    if (count==0){
        tempchar=strdup(stoken);//malloc and strcpy
```